# Avoid new when storing base-typed member variable that could be initialized with different derived types

Tags: c++, inheritance, new-operator

My code structure is like below where multiple classes implement Interface. In Example class I store a pointer to the Interface and new() it in the constructor appropriately (depending on constructor parameters not shown here). I'm looking for ways to avoid using new() in this scenario but haven't got a solution yet. What's the best practice for something like this?

```
class Interface
{
   virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

class A : public Interface
{
   void Foo() { ... }
};

class B : public Interface
{
   void Foo() { ... }
};

class Example
{
private:
     Interface* m_bar; 
public:
     Example()
     {
         m_bar = new A(); // deleted in destructor
     }
};
```

Comment: You don't nessiarily want to avoid new, you want to avoid worrying about ownership. Use a `std::unique_ptr` and be done with it.

Comment: And don't forget to give `Interface` a virtual destructor.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using new? please elaborate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways this is typically done, each with their own merits.

If A is truely defined at compile time, than a typical way to handle this is to simply use a template type:

```
template <typename T>
class TemplateExample
{
    T m_bar;
public:
    TemplateExample() : m_bar() {};
}
```

This has some downsides. `TemplateExample<A>` becomes unrelated to `TemplateExample<B>`, the error messages when `T` doesn't follow the correct interface are pretty obtuse, ect. The upside is this may use duck typing rather than interface typing, and m_bar is a concrete instance.

The other (arguable more common) way is to do the following

```
class UniquePtrExample
{
   std::unique_ptr<Interface> m_bar;
public:
   UniquePtrExample() : m_bar(new A()){}
};
```

This has the benefit of being able to be run time configuratble if you follow a cloable pattern:

```
class Interface
{
public:
   virtual void Foo() = 0;
   virtual Interface* clone() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class CloneHelper : public Interface
{
public:
     virtual Interface* clone() const { return new T(static_cast<const T&>(*this));}
};
class A : public CloneHelper<A>
{
   virtual void Foo() { std::cout << 'A' << std::endl; }
};

class B : public CloneHelper<B>
{
   virtual void Foo() { std::cout << 'B' << std::endl; }
};

class UniquePtrExample
{
   std::unique_ptr<Interface> m_bar;
public:
   UniquePtrExample() : m_bar(new A()){}
   UniquePtrExample(const Interface& i) : m_bar(i.clone());
};
```

Note you can further extend the above to have a move variant of the clone function.